# SQL Server: Performant way of getting data from two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I have to search in two tables that are in a parent-child relation (1:n) but in the result set I only need fields of the parent table. What is the most meaningfull way to do this? Is it one of the following simplified constructions ...

```
SELECT parent.fields FROM parent LEFT OUTER JOIN child ON [JoinExpr] 
   Where [ParentFilter] OR [ChildFilter] GROUP BY parent.fields 

SELECT DISTINCT(parent.fields) FROM parent LEFT OUTER JOIN child ON [JoinExpr]
   Where [ParentFilter] OR [ChildFilter]

SELECT parent.fields FROM parent Where [ParentFilter]  
   OR parent_id IN(SELECT parent_id FROM child WHERE [ChildFilter])
```

... or are there other, better possibilities? The data will be queried by ado.net.

Comment: The answer probably depends on how many rows you have in each table...

JOIN's tend to perform better over large data sets (depending on index order and other factors),
WHERE EXISTS may perform marginally better for small data sets

Comment: @neil fenwick: Can you prove that, allowing for the fact you may need DISTINCT in a JOIN?

Comment: @Neil Fenwick: Potentially, there are a lot of rows returned (some thousands), but in most cases, there are only a few (10 to 200)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select parent.fields
  from parent
 where <filters on parent columns>
   OR exists(
         select 'x' 
           from child 
          where child.parent_id = parent.parent_id
            and <filters on child columns>);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I have changed the AND of your SELECT to an OR. Works fine.

Comment: hehe, you beat me to the edit :) Also, please also accept the answer if you consider it to be the valid one for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you insisting on using an outer join.  From your description the results are going to come from the parent table and the child table will only be used as part of the restriction.  In this case you should use an inner join.  If the child table does not have a match on a specific criteria then it won't show in your results.  The performance will really come down to the fields that make up the join and the filter criteria.  Try to make sure that the fields in the join (foreign key) are indexed and where necessary the filter criteria fields are also indexed.  Don't use functions in the filter criteria e.g. where field1 >= DATEDIFF(???).  I forget the exact syntax for datediff.  This will mean that datediff is evaluated for each row in the full set of data.  In cases like this a sub-query can be useful

Comment: I need also results from the parent table when no records are found for the child table. That's why I made the OUTER JOIN.